# Full Outer join in KQL

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, azure-sentinel

KQL doesn't seem to have an equivalent for the SQL `FULL OUTER JOIN`. I want to return all records that don't intersect, in an SQL join it would look like this:

[image: SQL full outer join]

Looking at the [join documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/joinoperator?pivots=azuredataexplorer) for KQL it seems as though there is no equivalent. What's the best way to achieve this in KQL?

Am I correct in thinking the way to do this would be a `union` of a `leftanti` join and a `rightanti` join?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right, you need to do union of `leftanti` and `rightanti` joins:

**`Example KQL query:`**

```
let X1 = datatable(Key:string, Value1:long)
[
    'a',1,
    'b',2,
    'b',3,
    'c',4
];
let Y1 = datatable(Key:string, Value2:long)
[
    'b',10,
    'c',20,
    'c',30,
    'd',40
];
let right= X1 | join kind=rightanti Y1 on Key;
let left= X1 | join kind=leftanti Y1 on Key;
right 
| union left
```

**`Output:`**

[image]

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA4WPMQvCMBCF90D%20w21RyNC0TpX%20AndRxCG1scaGC9R0EPrjvZSqwQ7eLe8ej/clzgQ4KKig0YG2dma1M8/yEXqLrYS9doNRpfPYrjk7cQY0Qgup5KxrIfNEF299EXLD2XnLmSPE8Q8i/0VQlcqSrjw9is/RECX7Ynrb3kIVPzTC3VuEzmJTTa7GYOMzPALR57wz12U8mov01AGcjTCgJTeGXr0IJF88AQAA).

Comment: Why not just use the [fullouter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/join-fullouter) join?